# How do I load an ARGB_8888 Image with a normal DataInputStream?

Tags: java

**Edited:** Thanks for the previous answers and help! I've decided to edit this question into what I need exactly, sorry for not being as specific earlier.

Basically the title is all the information, this is currently what I'm working with:

```
int channels = 4;
int length = width * height;
int[] data = new int[length * channels];
int[][] channelPixels = new int[4][length];

for (int c = 0; c < channels; c++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        channelPixels[c][i] = readByte();
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the colors don't seem to match up to the originals.

Is there something I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: What is the link with Java? Do you want the equivalent code in Java?

Comment: `^` is pointer dereferencing. Would be difficult to mimic that in Java.

Comment: Yeah I'm looking for the equivalent code in java.

Comment: `Cardinal()` is not a function; it's a typecast. `^` is the dereference operator, used for working with pointers. It's pretty difficult to provide the equivalent code when you haven't provided any information about what `RawHdr` might be or what the code is supposed to do. With no context, and Delphi's support for declaring your own types, `RawHdr` could be just about anything.

Comment: 1 - Pointer arithmetics, sp will point to an offset of what s is pointing to. 2 - the byte dp pointing to will be assigned the byte sp is pointing to.

Comment: If it makes anything easier, here is the entire Delphi src: http://troll.ws/p/mgXLJ7

Comment: What I am trying to do is rewrite the texture exporter for Dungeon Siege 1, but in Java. I've already got everything including exporting the actual texture, but for some reason the color is off. (Red shows as the same shades but in blue.)

Comment: So what I'm trying to figure out is if I'm doing anything wrong when I'm doing "image.getRaster().setPixels(0, 0, width, height, color);" Here is the current function I'm working with: http://troll.ws/p/pNgA6l

And forgive me for it being so messy, it's just me doing trial and error. (Disregard me flipping the image, for some reason I had to do that to get the texture at the right rotation.)

Comment: @user946850 It probably translates to regular operations on byte arrays somehow. That said, I'm not sure if going about this by asking for help with manually porting specific snippets is the right way. (As opposed to actually understanding what the Delphi code does.)

Comment: If you're getting some specific glitches, you should consider writing equivalent unit tests for the Delphi and Java code and see what differences you get.

Comment: For exporting, I'm simply doing "ImageIO.write(in.getImage(raw.width, raw.height), "png", out);"

Comment: This code copies a rectangular buffer into a linear buffer one row at a time, starting with the bottom row. (That's why you had to flip the image.) Never mind what the specific syntax means. If it's the color you want to fix, then *that's* what you should have asked. Evidently, the pixel format is different. It might make more sense to fix the format afterward than to change how you write the data to begin with.

Comment: @RobKennedy Yeah I'm pretty sure the pixel format is different, also originally I was trying to figure out what was going on in the loops so I could see if the pixel format is different.

Comment: Unfortunately, there are no Wikipedia's with the pixel format for this file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code flips rectangular buffer and changes RGBA byte order to BGRA (or vice versa) like this:

```
a b c d e f g h
i j k l m n o p
=>
k j i l o n m p
c b a d g f e h
```

Rough analog with c/java-like pseudocode:

```
src = array of byte with length (RawHdr.Width * RawHdr.Height * 4)
dst = array of byte with the same length

dstindex = 0

for (i = RawHdr.Height - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
     srcstartindex = i * RawHdr.Width * 4;
     for (j = 0; j < RawHdr.Width; j++)
         {  
           si = srcstartindex + j * 4;
           dst[dstindex] = src[si + 2];
           dst[dstindex + 1] = src[si + 1];
           dst[dstindex + 2] = src[si];
           dst[dstindex + 3] = src[si + 3];
           dstindex +=4;
         }
     }
```

Comment: Thank you, you helped me figure it out. Turns out the format in the file says RGBA_8888 but it's actually BGRA for some reason..

Answer (score 3):

`Cardinal` is an unsigned integer, and `Typename(value)` is Delphi syntax for a typecast.  (The equivalent in C syntax is `(typename) value`.)  So `Cardinal()` isn't a function, it's casting the pointers as unsigned integers.

As a few people have already pointed out the `^` operator is a pointer dereference operator.  `dp^ := sp^` means "Set the value that `dp` points to equal to the value that `sp` is pointing to."

Pointers and pointer incrementing, such as is being used here, don't exist in Java, so this makes your job a lot trickier.  What you need to do if you want to do this in managed code is rewrite the entire thing in terms of arrays.

Comment: Thanks for the input, you've slightly demystified Delphi for me. I'd ^ but I can't. :S

Comment: @WalrusViking: you can't upvote yet, but as the owner of the question you can "accept" an answer. See "How does accepting an answer work?": http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

I am not going to write your code for you but these should help you:

[Cardinal](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=Cardinal&ExpandCode1=Yes), from the first link on Google, it is the basic unsigned integer type with a size that is not guaranteed.

`^` is a pointer dereference.